# How does vmware guest OS memory usage work?

Tags: vmware-workstation

If I use vmware workstation v6.5 on a vista 32-bit host with 8GB memory, will a 64-bit guest OS (win7) be able to use more than 4GB physical memory (depending on vmware memory settings)?

Comment: This thread has 2 completely contradictory answers on this: 

http://communities.vmware.com/message/1265695;jsessionid=C9BD948EA24781483F8A33096939E168#1265695

Comment: Probably that person, who gave contradictory answer, thought that he has 64-bit OS as a _host_. Or just took a wild guess, without trying it himself :]

Comment: refer also: http://communities.vmware.com/thread/219571

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Someone already tried that](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1227857#1227857) (besides the one that [you have found](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1265695;jsessionid=C9BD948EA24781483F8A33096939E168#1265695)), and it appears that it is not possible.

If you will install 64-bit OS as **host**, then it will work. But VMWare can't use more RAM than the amount host OS can provide.

Comment: +1 All virtual machine software is limited by the amount of memory that can be physcally addressed.

Answer (score 1):

No, because it is the host OS which allocates memory for the guest (the 32-bit virtualization program). No 32-bit program will be able to access over 4GB of memory with a 32-bit address space.

Comment: +1 and you can create a 64-bit guest with more than 4GB, but anything over that will be paging and not actually addressing any physical RAM beyond 4GB.