# 64-bit guest OS on 32-bit host OS => usable RAM?

Tags: 64-bit, virtualization, 32-bit

I've read that you can run a 64-bit guest OS on a 32-bit host OS through virtualisation (Hyper-V or sth. similar).

How much RAM can the guest OS use/allocate in this case? (assuming 4GB+ RAM)

[image]

Comment: Which Software are you using to do virtualization ?

Comment: Duplicates here http://superuser.com/questions/15434/how-does-vmware-guest-os-memory-usage-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Guest OS can't access more Memory than your Host OS.

Comment: added an image - so the RAM is managed by the host OS and not by the Hypervisor?

Comment: @Milde The memory is Managed by the OS at the software Level, so the Guest can't have more memory than the Host.

Comment: ty, I marked the answer as "the correct answer". I also figured out, that that you need a 64bit system to run Hyper-V on it. :)